# Pipe between two child processes

Tags: rust, pipe

I want to implement pipes between two child processes to execute something like `env | grep USER`. This is what I already have but doesn't work:

```
let mut child1 = Command::new(cmd1)
    .args(args1)
    .stdout(Stdio::piped())
    .spawn()
    .unwrap();

let pipe = child1.stdout.take().unwrap();
let mut child2 = Command::new(cmd2)
    .args(args2)
    .stdin(pipe)
    .stdout(Stdio::piped())
    .spawn()
    .unwrap();
```

It doesn't show any errors.

Comment: `Stdio::piped` makes your Rust parent process the other side of the pipeline. That's not what you want here; for child1, the other side should be child2, and the parent shouldn't have any copy of the FIFO open at all.

Comment: Take a look at https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Stdio.html#method.from-2 -- the example is _exactly_ what you need.

Comment: If the above link gives you what you need to answer your own question, please consider using the "Add an Answer" button to add an answer describing how to solve the problem. (I'd do so myself if I had time to repro/test, but I'm at work right now, so it makes sense for you to take the credit / get the internet points if you have the opportunity).

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

After digging through the Rust source code and documentation (seems the docs don't clearly cover this usecase), I found a way to do it without `unsafe` code or external libraries.

Try something like this:

```rust
use std::error::Error;
use std::process::{Command, Stdio};

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let child1 = Command::new("ls")
        .stdout(Stdio::piped())
        .spawn()
        .unwrap();

    let mut child2 = Command::new("wc")
        .stdin(Stdio::from(child1.stdout.unwrap()))
        .spawn()
        .unwrap();

    child1.wait()?;
    child2.wait()?;
    Ok(())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that I have found, with the help of: [How to implement redirection of stdout of a child process to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42726095/how-to-implement-redirection-of-stdout-of-a-child-process-to-a-file)

My knowledge of Rust is scarce but I will try to explain. I interpret this code as if was written in C so: With `pipe()`, I make a `fd`. Then, using `from_raw_fd()`—this is something that I don't know if I understood—I give the ownership of `stdin` and `stdout` `fd` to two variables that I later use to replace the output of the first command and the input of the second command connecting both programs with the pipe.

Here's the final code:

```
use std::process::{Command, Stdio};
use std::os::unix::io::FromRawFd;
use nix::unistd::pipe;


let fd = pipe().unwrap();

let (pipe_in,pipe_out) = unsafe {
    (Stdio::from_raw_fd(fd.0),
    Stdio::from_raw_fd(fd.1))
};


let child1 = Command::new(cmd2.1)
    .args(cmd2.0)
    .stdout(pipe_out)
    .spawn()
    .unwrap();

let mut child2 = Command::new(cmd1.1)
    .args(cmd1.0)
    .stdin(pipe_in)
    .spawn()
    .unwrap();


child2.wait().unwrap();
```

I hope someone finds it useful.