# Combine files with cat

Tags: rust, cat

I am trying to combine files with `cat` using Rust. Below is some example code that is erroring with the below error.

```
use std::process::Command as cmd;
cmd::new("/bin/cat")
    .arg("1.txt 2.txt > 3.txt")
    .spawn()
    .expect("Failure");
```

`/bin/cat: '1.txt 2.txt > 3.txt': No such file or directory`

I also tried adding it as multiple arguments with

```
cmd::new("/bin/cat")
    .args("1.txt 2.txt", ">", "3.txt")
    .spawn()
    .expect("Failure");
```

which errors out with

```
/bin/cat: '1.txt 2.txt': No such file or directory
/bin/cat: '>': No such file or directory
/bin/cat: 3.txt: No such file or directory
```

I've tried with `cmd::new("/bin/sh")` but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Args of `/bin/cat` are `"1.txt"` and `"2.txt"`. `>` and the rest is implemented by bash. You should call `cat` with `.args("1.txt", "2.txt")` and pipe `stdout` into a file similarly to this (answer)[https://stackoverflow.com/a/42726499/8564999]

Comment: Thanks for that! Want to open an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov `args` takes an array, so it would be `.args(["1.txt", "2.txt"])`, but same idea.

Comment: or, if you have the shell command in mind, you can also try `cmd::new("/bin/sh").args(["-c", "cat 1.txt 2.txt > 3.txt"])`. This will cost a `fork()+exec()` more and argument parsing (by the shell) but its easier on the rust side ;^)

Comment: Why are you using `cat`? The Rust standard library can do this easily, without spawning a command: `let f1 = std::fs::read_to_string("1.txt").unwrap(); let f2 = std::fs::read_to_string("2.txt").unwrap(); std::fs::write("3.txt", f1 + &f2).unwrap();`

Comment: @Aloso maybe `cat` here is a trivial way to make a minimal example and the real need actually relies on running another external process? In the same idea as your remark: why use Rust at all, when the existing `cat` works perfectly? ;^)

Comment: @prog-fh I find that hard to believe, since the OP said specifically that they're trying to combine files. "Why use Rust at all?" Maybe combining the files is only _part_ of what the program is supposed to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two examples considering the suggestions in the comments.

```rust
fn main() {
    // redirect output from rust
    std::process::Command::new("/bin/cat")
        .args(["1.txt", "2.txt"])
        .stdout(std::fs::File::create("3.txt").unwrap())
        .spawn()
        .expect("spawn failure")
        .wait()
        .expect("wait failure");
    //
    // rely on the shell for redirection
    std::process::Command::new("/bin/sh")
        .args(["-c", "cat 1.txt 2.txt >3_bis.txt"])
        .spawn()
        .expect("spawn failure")
        .wait()
        .expect("wait failure");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I am quite new to Rust so things like this still get me tripped up.

Comment: one benefit of the shell method is that it will respect your `PATH`. not really an issue for `cat`, but if something lived in `/usr/bin` instead of `/bin`, calling `sh` first will fix that.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler and more robust solution is to use `std::fs` instead of `cat`:

```rust
use std::fs;

let file1 = fs::read_to_string("1.txt").expect("1.txt could not be opened");
let file2 = fs::read_to_string("2.txt").expect("2.txt could not be opened");

fs::write("3.txt", file1 + "\n" + &file2).expect("3.txt could not be written");
```

Note that this doesn't depend on `cat`, it works on every platform and operating system, and it allows handling each error properly.

Comment: Depending on file size, it would be troublesome to merge both files in a single string via `file1 + "\n" + &file2`

Comment: I added in text files for the cat example but it was actually audio files, I just didn't want to hear people telling me I shouldn't use cat and should use <insert package here> instead. So I do appreciate the answer (upvoted it) and will keep it in mind, unless there is a way to do the same with an audio file(?) I'll still likely use cat.